# Wordpress add a rewrite rule to a page to accept a GET variable

Tags: rewrite-rules, query-variable

I want to rewrite

**mysite.com/events/submission/test-event-01**

to

**mysite.com/events/submission?epl=test-event-01**

This is what I have done so far without any result. I get a 404 error (*mysite.com/events/submission/test-event-01*). Can anyone suggest the correct rule?

```php
add_action( 'init', 'epl_rewrite');
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'epl_query_vars');
        
function epl_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^submission/([^/]*)[/]?', 'index.php?pagename=submission&epl=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
        
function epl_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'epl';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

**Note:**

1. Permalinks are re-saved to flush the rewrite rules.
2. *mysite.com/events/submission* page is already added.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: GET variables aren't a part of the pretty permalinks/rewrite rules system, and you don't need to register GET variables as query vars ( not unless you intend to map part of a pretty URL onto it ). If you want people who visit `mysite.com/events/submission/test-event-01` to instead see `mysite.com/events/submission?epl=test-event-01` then that's not a rewrite, that's a redirect. WP Rewrite rules are for mapping pretty URLs on to ugly URLs of the form `index.php?foo=bar`, they aren't redirects.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I will keep a note on this. My purpose is now served with `get_query_var`.

Answer (score 0):

Since '*submission*' is a child page of '*events*', the rewrite rule should include the parent path

```
add_rewrite_rule('events/([^/]*)/submission/?', 'index.php?pagename=events/submission&epl=$matches[1]', 'top');
```